# Building React Native App with VS Appcenter - p12 wrong password?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I'm following [this tutorial](https://vdelacou.medium.com/test-and-develop-ios-app-on-your-iphone-with-microsoft-windows-befa9e87631d) to get a react native app built using windows to run on my iOS device.

When I upload my p12 certificate, I am prompted for the password I supplied when I created it, but this build fails with the following error

```
security: SecKeychainItemImport: MAC verification failed during PKCS12 import (wrong password?)
##[error]Error: The process '/usr/bin/security' failed with exit code 1
##[section]Finishing: Install Apple certificate
```

The password is correct, and if I enter a wrong password intentionally at the point of upload, the appcenter UI says that the password is wrong so you can’t even get to the build step if this is incorrect in the first place.

Am I missing something?